# SQL INSERT INTO is not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to add some Values to a Database with PHP I send some parametres from a Android Application they also arrive in the right way. I checked it with echo and printed all the Parameteres I send.

```
id (PRIMARY_KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT)

deviceID (TEXT)

name (TEXT)

latitude (TEXT)

longitude (TEXT)
```

Thats the Structure and the name of the Database is position

This is my query but it just doesent work.

```
$deviceID = $_POST['deviceID'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO position(deviceID, name, latitude, longitude) VALUES('$deviceID', '$name', '$latitude', '$longitude')");
```

Comment: There is one glaring reason this may fail - you have not escaped your input in any way.  A single quote in any input field will break the whole query.  For example `$name = "Mr. O'Brien";` will break your query, and it is highly vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `echo mysql_error()` and my bet is on `check the manual for the correct syntax to use near` followed by some word from your input.

Comment: first of all use `mysqli_()` secondly sanitize your input, atleast use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: At a minimum, you must call these as `$deviceID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['deviceID'])`

Comment: can you try to use @mysql_query, this will stop warning messages to execute the query

Comment: @kidz No no no no no no no!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Don't advocate `@`. Fix errors, never hide them!

Comment: use PDO. mysql_* is bad news.

Comment: if the column is INT, it's better/faster to store them without quotes in the query. Although quotes in the query still works.

Comment: I have an manual error as Michael said. And no I am using no quotes in the name.

Comment: There is also no column that will use a INT they are all TEXT and need TEXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_position

`Position` is a function name in MySQL: you should escape it using backticks (`), and you need to add a space between `position` and the parentheses.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `position` (deviceID, name, latitude, longitude) VALUES('$deviceID', '$name', '$latitude', '$longitude')");
```

Comment: It's a function name but [not a reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) so it is the space causing the problem not the quoting - it's being misinterpreted as a function call.

Comment: Yes I only forgot the space -.-

Answer (score 0):

Listen, you need to stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.  They will cause you a lot of headache.  I suggest you setup mysql to use `PDO`.  Here is an example.

Connect to it first and have it throw exceptions for you to handle yourself.

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Now run your update.

```
try { 
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO position VALUES(:deviceId, :name, :latitude, :longitude)');
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':deviceId' => $deviceID,
    ':name' => $name,
    ':latitude' => $latitude,
    ':longitude' => $longitude 
  ));

  // Affected Rows?
  echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1

} catch(PDOException $e) {

  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

// Per your question to json_encode

After you call the `execute()` statement the same way (but with a `SELECT`) you will just need to do this.

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // This will be an array
$json_results = json_encode($results);
```

Later down the line if you want to get it as an object (which I prefer to work with)

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Also if you want to get a single result, use `fetch()`

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I am using JSON to encode the results and then echo them how can I do this with PDO?

Comment: It was only the space in my query. Thank you very much for your solution to I will take a look in PDO and what advantages I have